# How to input more information in BST and use entry number as key to access it?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have been wondering, how can I make a library managament program where the insert will ask the name of the Author, the title of the book, and entry number. The entry number will be used as the key to access the information. I have managed to make it to ask entry number but I have no idea how to add the two other questions as I'm clueless where and how to store the additional data. Any solution? I'm not well-versed in BST... Also, this code aren't entirely mine.

This is the insert

```
void insert(char* key, struct node** leaf, Compare cmp)
{
    int res;
    if( *leaf == NULL ) {
        *leaf = (struct node*) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        (*leaf)->value = malloc( strlen (key) +1 );     // memory for key
        strcpy ((*leaf)->value, key);                   // copy the key
        (*leaf)->p_left = NULL;
        (*leaf)->p_right = NULL;
        //printf(  "\nnew node for %s" , key);
    } else {
        res = cmp (key, (*leaf)->value);
        if( res < 0)
            insert( key, &(*leaf)->p_left, cmp);
        else if( res > 0)
            insert( key, &(*leaf)->p_right, cmp);
        else                                            // key already exists
            printf ("Key '%s' already in tree\n", key);
    }
}
```

This is the input on the main.

```
char *input( void )
{
    static char line[MAXLEN+1];       // where to place key    
    printf("\nInput entry number : ");
    fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin );
    return ( strtok(line, "\n" ));    // remove trailing newline
}
```

For additional information:

```
void menu()
{
    printf("\n1. Insert a book");
    printf("\n2. Search for an element");
    printf("\n3. Display an element");
    printf("\n4. Destroy Tree");
    printf("\n5. Exit");
    printf("\nEnter your choice: ");    
}

int main()
{
    struct node *p_root = NULL;
    char *value;
    char option = 'x';

    while( option != 'q' ) {
        //displays menu for program
        menu();

        //gets the char input to drive menu
        option = getch();           // instead of two getchar() calls

        if( option == '1') {
            value = input();
            printf ("Inserting %s\n", value);
            insert(value,  &p_root, (Compare)CmpStr);
        }
        else if( option == '2' ) {
            value = input();
            search(value, p_root, (Compare)CmpStr);     // no need for **
        }
        else if( option == '3' ) {
            in_order(p_root);
        }
        else if( option == '4' ) {
            delete_tree(&p_root);
            printf("Tree destroyed");
            p_root = NULL;
        }
        else if( option == '5' ) {
            printf("Quitting");
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can create two character arrays in the Node information (Struct) to store the Author and Title of the book. Will that satisfy your requirements? (I guess it will )

Comment: What does BST mean here ?

Comment: @pifor: BST = binary search tree, i.e. a binary tree where nodes are ordered by a key.